# Content scripts sendMessage receives null back if options page has onMessage listener

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a web-extension adddon that's comprised of my Background Script, Content Scripts and an options_ui page. The Content Scripts message the Background script using `browser.runtime.sendMessage` and expect a response back from that with the information it needs, quite often. The Background script listens with `browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener`.

The options page preforms an action that can take between 1 to 5 minutes, so it tells the Background script to do it, and the background script response with a progress update every 1% through `browser.tabs.sendMessage`. The options pager registers a `browser.runtime.onMessage` listener to listen for this update.

The problem is that as long as the options page is open, the content scripts are unable to receive any responses from the background script. Any response it gets is always null. The Background script definitely receives the request from the content script, and response with the correct information, but the script doesn't receive the response. Even if I have multiple content-scripts open, and if I register a `browser.runtime.onMessage` listener on each of them the way I do for the options page, it work *as long as the options page is closed*.

I'm not really sure what's going on here or what the next steps are. I know that the documentation for `runtime.onMessage` say that only one listener may respond if two are registered on the same document, but unless the options page counts as the same document as the background script, that doesn't really make sense. I know it's not a Firefox only issue, as the exact same behavior occurs in Chrome as well.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `connect` in your case ? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect

Comment: @TarunLalwani I'm still really curious why this occurs in the first place, but changing to port messaging does solve my issue. If you post it as an answer, I'm happy to award you the bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any documentation which explains or documents that Option page is also part of the pages

> Note: If multiple pages are listening for onMessage events, only the first to call sendResponse() for a particular event will succeed in sending the response. All other responses to that event will be ignored.

But as mentioned in the documentation

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect

> ## Long-lived connections
>
> Sometimes it's useful to have a conversation that lasts longer than a single request and response. In this case, you can open a long-lived channel from your content script to an extension page , or vice versa, using runtime.connect or tabs.connect, respectively . The channel can optionally have a name, allowing you to distinguish between different types of connections.

You should be using `connect` for your use-case

Comment: Why this is accepted answer? sendMessage return should always return to the sender why existing options page shoul break this behavior?